# Angular 1.5 bootstrap popover isn't functioning as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get popovers working on a test app im currently working on. I have loaded the HTML as such:

```
<button uib-popover-template="'popover-content.html'" popover-title="test" type="button" popover-placement="'bottom'" class="btn btn-default">
  testingPopover
</button>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover-content.html">
    <div>
      <label>You have no new</label>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have inside my index file (which calls all these other components):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <style>
    /* This helps the ng-show/ng-hide animations start at the right place. */
    /* Since Angular has this but needs to load, this gives us the class early. */

    .ng-hide {
      display: none!important;
    }
  </style>
  <title ng-bind="title">
    toDoList
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <base href="/">

  <!-- build:css styles/lib.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/toastr/toastr.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:css styles/app.css -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/.tmp/styles.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/client/styles/styles1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container formatting">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" >
          <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <!-- build:js js/lib.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/extras.angular.plus/ngplus-overlay.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/ng-lodash/build/ng-lodash.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js js/app.js -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="/src/client/app/app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/exception/exception.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/logger/logger.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/router/router.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/core/core.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/layout.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/app.states.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/exception/exception-handler.provider.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/exception/exception.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/logger/logger.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/blocks/router/router-helper.provider.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/core/constants.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/connection-service.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/creation.component.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/display.component.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/list.component.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/media.component.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/todoList.component.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/client/app/layout/btnPopover.component.js"></script>
  <!-- endinject -->

  <!-- inject:templates:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>
```

When i run the code the button 'testingPopover' is successfully showing however when i click on this button there is no popover displaying. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, I've been referencing https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to build what i have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have since continued investigation and come to an answer for the issue, for those who are looking for answers that might have a similar issue to the one I described I will highlight my process.

The issue was a fault in the inclusion of bootstrap into the module, inside the app.module.js file i added in 'ui.bootstrap' as a dependency.

My app.module.js looks like this now:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [
    'app.core',
    'app.ui.router',
    'app.layout',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ]);
})();
```

I believe the issue was that ui.bootstrap whilst defined in the application correctly wasn't actually a dependency at all and hence wasn't running (perhaps someone could comment to confirm).

Thankyou to those who took the time to edit, and look at this post.